# Why does _ret evaluate to true, shouldn't it evaluate to false (Bit Operator)?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, compound-assignment

```
class Program
{
    private static bool _ret = true;

    static void Main()
    {
        _ret &= Method();
        Console.WriteLine(_ret);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static bool Method()
    {
        _ret &= false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

We came across this issue in a larger application we are developing and was wondering if it was expected functionality? This is written in c# with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Um, because it invokes `return true` ?

Comment: I think he is asking about the value of _ret rather than Method(). Am I right user858462?

Comment: Yes i meant the value of _ret.

Comment: Its returning true because true & true = true, which is essentially what your final expression is evaluating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by Eric Lippert in his blog post "Precedence vs Associativity vs Order",

> The expression F() + G() * H() is equivalent to F() + (G() * H()), but
>   C# does NOT evaluate G() * H() before F(). Rather, this is equivalent
>   to:
>
> temp1 = F();
>
> temp2 = G();
>
> temp3 = H();
>
> temp4 = temp2 * temp3;
>
> result = temp1 + temp4;

So in your case, it evaluates _ret prior to calling Method(), and the fact that _ret changes inside Method() does not affect the outer call.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that _ret &= Method() is translated to _ret = _ret & Method() and the _ret on the RHS is being evaluated before Method() is called.

Since _ret is true initially, it's true when it evaluates _ret in the RHS, and then _ret is changed to false in Method(), but that doesn't matter since Method() returns true and true & true = true.

This is probably compiler/environment specific... it relies on left-to-right evaluation, which you shouldn't count on.

Comment: It'd help to know which language this is. If it's Java, then there shouldn't be any such thing as "compiler specific".

Comment: +1 for "it relies on left-to-right evaluation, which you shouldn't count on."

Comment: @Kerrek: True, but either way, he shouldn't assume that this code will work the same when translated to e.g. C++, Python, or Ada.

Comment: If this were C++, would that be a violation of reading a variable more than once before a sequence point?

Comment: In C# you can rely on left-to-right evaluation; that's in the language specification.

Comment: @Eric: Still, I think you'd agree it's not a good habit to get into. In general, relying on side-effects is bad, outside of very well-understood OOP constructs. At the very least, you should know that it's OK to expect this in C# because it's in the specification... knowledge is key here.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. *Relying on an obscure language rule about the order in which side effects are observed to happen* is bad. *Calling a method that is useful for both its value and its side effects* is bad too!

Answer (score 0):

Your method return shoule be like below

```
    private static bool Method() 
    {
        return _ret &= false; 
    }
```